# Python Methods (where to find additional resources)

Tags: python, function, methods, attributes

I am learning Python by reading books, and I have a question about methods. Basically, all of the books that I am reading touch on methods and act like they just come out of thin air. For example, where can I find a list of all methods that can be applied? I can't find any documentation that lists all methods.

The books are using things like .uppercase and .lowercase but is not saying **where** to find other methods to use, or how to see which ones are available and where. I would just like to know what I am missing. Thanks. Do I need to dig into Python documentation to find all of the methods?

Comment: Every class has its own set of methods. There isn't one global list. So, for example, you can find all of the string methods (methods of class `str`, including `.upper()` and `.lower()`) in the documentation for class `str`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods and likewise methods of `float` objects are at https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-complex . But there you have to look at two sets of methods, one set common to all numeric types and another set specific to `float` objects. So, yes, you do have to read the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of function in Python's modules. If you want to learn were you can find them, you should ask what you want. For example there is a random module and you can find some functions like `random.randint`.